# How can I launch and query ngrok in Linux from C# .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, ngrok

We've got a kestrel-based console-driven web app that auto-launches ngrok on startup. We use Process.Start() pointing to ngrok.exe, then in the same C# we query http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels to get the ngrok URL so we can sync out to the external dependency.

It's been working in Windows. In Linux--I'm using MX Linux--when I step through the code in Rider, Process.Start returns true, and by the time we reach the code to query http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels the process object still says .HasExited == false. However, at that point it fails (Connection Refused), and if I open another terminal and `wget -O - http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnel` that fails to connect as well, so I'm really confused, did ngrok start or not? If in the terminal I manually navigate to where the Linux executable file is for ngrok and pass the same arguments I was passing into Process.Start(), it does start up, it fills the screen, and opening another terminal and trying `wget -O - http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnel` it successfully connects and returns output.

I mean, if the process fails to start from C#, why would `Process.Start()` return true? .. and why would the process object, even after some thread sleep, say `.HasExited` == `false`?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I had a hunch that it was related to the console streams being blocked by some of the ProcessStartInfo details since using the shell works differently in Linux than Windows. Here's the working code, noting the change was adding the if block at the beginning:

```
 if (Company.RuntimeEnvironment.IsLinux && showWindow == "true")
     { showWindow = "false"; }
 var process = new Process
 {
     StartInfo =
     {
        FileName = FileNgrokExecutable,
        CreateNoWindow = showWindow != "true" && showWindow != "integrated",
        RedirectStandardOutput = showWindow != "true" && showWindow != "integrated",
        RedirectStandardError = showWindow != "true" && showWindow != "integrated",
        UseShellExecute = showWindow == "true",
        Arguments = $"http {localPort} -host-header=localhost"
    }
};
```